# Table row count confusion PHP Foreach array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, html-table

I have array like this

```
Array  ([0] => 8 [1] => 8 [2] => 1 [3]=> 7 [4] => 8 )
```

and I formed table row with above array using ForEach on PHP. But when you look at the above array will create 7 TDs on 3rd ROW and and 8 TDs on 4th ROW. I need to move that blank TD on 3rd Row at start of row instead showing it at end of row.. Is it possible??

```
<table border="1"><tbody>
  <tr align="right">
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_02">02</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_06">06</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_10">10</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_14">14</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_18">18</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_22">22</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_26">26</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_30">30</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="right">
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_01">01</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_05">05</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_09">09</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_13">13</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_17">17</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_21">21</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_25">25</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_29">29</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="right">
    <td>XX</td>
    <td>XX</td>
    <td>XX</td>
    <td>XX</td>
    <td>XX</td>
    <td>XX</td>
    <td>XX</td>
    <td>XX</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="right">
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_03">03</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_07">07</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_11">11</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_15">15</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_19">19</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_23">23</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_27">27</td>
  </tr>
  <tr align="right">
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_31">31</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_04">04</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_08">08</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_12">12</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_16">16</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_20">20</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_24">24</td>
    <td align="right" colspan="0" rowspan="0" id="td_28">28</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: Also show your php code with which you created the html part.
And best also describe how the table SHOULD look like as that is not 100% conclusive from your initial post.

Comment: I dont' see a 'blank TD' in 3rd row...

Comment: According to the array the third table row (array[2]) should only have one td, it would really help if you showed us your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got absolutely no idea how you are generating your table, but..

One way to avoid the "blank" td issue is to make sure all rows have the same amount of td's, which can be done by finding the `max` value of the array.

For example:

```
<?php
    $row_array = array(8, 8, 1, 7, 8);
    $num_tds = max($row_array);
?>
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <?php foreach($row_array as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
        <?php for ($i = 0; $i < $num_tds; $i++) : ?>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <?php endfor; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Without actually seeing your code I am just offering blind solutions but I hope it helps.